# Pixelated font (font-face) on Windows (IE and Firefox)

Tags: css, windows, fonts, font-face

We're currently building a website for a large audience and most of the test users are using Windows. They noticed a very distorted font rendering, see Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot - Normal Text and Bold Text]

I tried some "fixes" I could find, like adding a subtle text-shadow, using zoom: 1 and/or setting translateZ(0). I also tried using filter and font-smoothing properties, but the font is not getting better.

I'm using a font-face (Texta Narrow). Firefox on Windows looks even worse than IE9.

Is there any way to smoothen the text at least a little, or is my only option to use another font?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using font-face in your website, so you should to change the font-face declaration/format, like this.

```
font-family: 'fontName';
src: url('fontName.eot');
src: url('fontName.svg#fontNameID') format('svg'),
     url('fontName.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fontName.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fontName.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Comment: How is that going to change the rendering? I'm using the standard way provided by fonts.com to implement the font-face.